# AngularJS - Why asynchronous validators are not called when other validators fail?

Tags: angularjs, validation, asynchronous, angularjs-directive

Is not that I don't like or anything, but the problem is that synchronous validators behave differently. They are always called, even if other validator failed before. So, there is an uneven behaviour in validators, that also can cause some problems.

I tested all this with a simple program.

I created a synchronous validator and an asynchronous validator that validate exactly the same.
In both validators I submit an error in the "typical" way with:

```
ctrl.$validators.sync= function(modelValue,viewValue){...
```

and I also submit an additional error(for example to tell there was a connection problem in the asynchronous validation) with:

```
ctrl.$setValidity('syncplus',...
```

Also, beside the uneven behaviour, the additional validation error causes and additional problem in asynchronous validators:

As I have seen, async "typical" validation is always reset immediatelly if input is modified. (I don't know where)
But the additional validator is never reset. And, as async validator is not called when other validator fails, I can't update the additional validator, so the error from before is still shown, even though it can be a valid input.

Please, [try my program in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZHFlMd):

Here you can see the js code whith the validators:

```
angular.module('app',[])
.directive('async', function($q,$timeout){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl){

            var nono_username= ['a','aa','aaa','aaaaa']; // SHOULD FAIL from 1 to 5 a's, BUT NOT with 4 a's

            ctrl.$asyncValidators.async= function(modelValue,viewValue){

                scope.data.called+= 'A'; // This way we know Async has been called
                var def= $q.defer();

                $timeout(function() { // Mock a delayed response
                    if(nono_username.indexOf(modelValue)===-1){ // The username is available
                        ctrl.$setValidity('asyncplus',true);
                        def.resolve();
                    } else {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('asyncplus',false);
                        def.reject();
                    }
                }, 200);

                return def.promise;
            };
        }
    };
})
.directive('sync', function($q){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl){

            var nono_username= ['a','aa','aaa','aaaaa']; // SHOULD FAIL from 1 to 5 a's, BUT NOT with 4 a's

            ctrl.$validators.sync= function(modelValue,viewValue){
                scope.data.called+= 'S'; // This way we know Sync has been called
                ctrl.$setValidity('syncplus',nono_username.indexOf(modelValue)===-1);
                return nono_username.indexOf(modelValue)===-1;
            };
        }
    };
})
/* Maybe a solution for resetting asyncplus?
.directive('asyncplus', function($q){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl){
            ctrl.$validators.asyncplus= function(modelValue,viewValue){
                return true;
            };
        }
    };
})
*/
.controller('Controller',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.data= {username:'',called:''};
}]);
```

**Conclusion:**

- Why asynchronous validators are not called when other validators
  fail?
- Why additional $setValidity validators are not reset?
- Can I reset ALL validators in a simple way? (I found that creating a
  synchronous validator with the same name and include the directive in
  the input solves it, as I put in the commented code above)
- What do you think is the best option to avoid all this problems or
  wich workaround I should use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use $parsers and $formatters if you want it to work like that:

```
.directive('async', function($q,$timeout){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl){

            var nono_username= ['a','aa','aaa','aaaaa']; // SHOULD FAIL from 1 to 5 a's, BUT NOT with 4 a's

            var validate = function(value) {

                $timeout(function() { // Mock a delayed response
                    if(nono_username.indexOf(value)===-1){ // The username is available
                        ctrl.$setValidity('asyncplus',true);
                    } else {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('asyncplus',false);
                    }
                }, 200);

                return value;
            };

            ctrl.$parsers.push(validate);
            ctrl.$formatters.push(validate);
        }
    };
})
```